# Calculating overall rating

Tags: php, mysql, math, logic

If i have a series of 10 objects with rating from 1 to 10. Then how can i calculate overall rating?

For example if i have a list like this:

```
Entertainment - 8/10
Fun - 9/10
Comedy - 6/10
Dance - 8/10
```

and so on... Like this 10 objects. Tell me how to calculate the overall rating for 10.

```
Overall - ?/10
```

I am very weak in maths. I was told by someone to add the total and if I got 83 as the answer, then the overall rating will be 8.3/10. Is this correct?

I am doing this for my PHP website. So if someone knows how to write a query for this, that would be very helpful for me.

Comment: yes 83/10 is correct, the query would depend on your db structure which you have not shown us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Average the total rating and you will get the answer.

he one that is told for will stand correct if there are 10 criteria on which scoring is to be made.

```
SELECT avg(score) FROM tbl
```

There is inbuilt function available for it 
Refer 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to get the average, add them all together and divide by the amount. Example:

```
//do a MySQL query instead of this
$result_out_of_10 = array(
    'fun' => 9,
    'comedy' => 6,
    'dance' => 8
);

$total = 0;
$total_results = 0;
foreach( $result_out_of_10 as $result )
{
    $total += $result;
    $total_results++;
}

$final_average_out_of_10 = $total / $total_results;
print "Average rating: $final_average_out_of_10 out of 10.";
```

**EDIT:** Meherzad has a better way - using the MySQL `AVG()` function - which I didn't know about. Use his way instead (although mine still works, it's more code than necessary).

Comment: @Dagon I'm not going to *delete* it as it may be useful one day for someone else. But yes I have upvoted his - as it is a better way.

Comment: lol, that explains my garage full of junk, it may be useful one day :-)